# Install and execute Wkhtmltopdf on linux Redhat server 64bit (using PHP)

Tags: php, linux, redhat, wkhtmltopdf, shell-exec

I am using Linux Redhat 64bit.My server info is

`Linux ************* 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5xen #1 SMP Mon Feb 21 06:01:41 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

To create PDF i am using Wkhtmltopdf.

So that First i installed wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-**amd64**.tar.bz2
when i execute the commands.It shows **segmentation fault** error.

So i reinstalled wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-**i386**.tar.bz2, it shows **wkhtmltopdf: symbol lookup error: wkhtmltopdf: undefined symbol: FcFreeTypeQueryFace** error.

How can i fix the error?Any Solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a Qt-originating error about fontconfig, it (or a very similar issue) has been [reported in the wkhtmltopdf issues list and there is a workaround/fix there](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=352) that you could try.